# Group by dates in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo issue on currently working project need some help from you.

Below is my issue:

I have store my user log data as a sample:

db.visitors collection

```
 [
    {
        uid: "0001",
        logPath: "/home",
        logTime: "Mon Dec 27 2010 18:51:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
    },
    {
        uid: "0002",
        logPath: "/",
        logTime: "Mon Dec 27 2010 18:51:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
    },
    {
        uid: "0001",
        logPath: "/product",
        logTime: "Mon Dec 27 2010 18:51:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
    },
    {
        uid: "0001",
        logPath: "/order",
        logTime: "Mon Dec 28 2010 18:51:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
    }
]
```

And I need to group my visit user by date (between Mon Dec 28 2010 and Mon Dec 27 2010)

Try to find log of the user with uid is 0001 and group:

```
[
    {
        date: "Mon Dec 28",
        log: [
            {
                logPath: '/order'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        date: "Mon Dec 27",
        log: [
            {
                logPath: '/home'
            },
            {
                logPath: '/product'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

please guide me how do I group it

Comment: Are the dates really strings?

Comment: All dates in Date object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.aggregate([
    {$match: {uid: "0001", logTime: {$gte: ISODate('Mon Dec 27 2010'), $lt: ISODate("Mon Dec 29 2010")}}},
    {$project: 
        {day: {'$dayOfMonth': '$logTime'},month: {'$month':'$logTime'},year: {'$year':'$logTime'} }
    },
    {$group: {
        _id: {day:'$day',month:'$month',year:'$year'},
        log: {$push:{logPath:'$logPath'}}
    }}
])
```

Something like that should do the trick. If you want to group by only month then you can take out the `day` field from the `_id` of the `$group`.

There is another way of doing dates but I must admit this way is probably the easiest at the moment.

Comment: If you want-- you can omit the `{$project:..}` step since the `{$dayOfMonth:...}` operators and the like work inside a `{$group:...}`.

Comment: @Conrad.Dean indeed, though I (personally) think it looks rather hard to read

Comment: totally fair.  Hey-- do you know if it's possible to use them in `{$match:..}`?  I've been wanting to avoid filtering with `ISODate()`

Comment: @Conrad.Dean Not without index loss, However, if you were to pull out the parts first and then do a `$match` pipeline...but that losses indexes, using indexes I do not believe it is possible, `$match` is a direct prototype to `find()`

Comment: @Conrad.Dean the index loss you would get is that no index can be used to do the $match which means that it will attempt to project the entire collection into memory and then do a full table scan on it. As for reading up on it it is somewhere within the aggregation framework docs, cant remember exactly where